# Stuck trying to make a helper method to Save DB changes with catching

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm working on a project with a C# MVC using Entity Framework 6.0 and I have a bunch of models like Customer, Promotion, Messages, and in all of them, I'm pretty space inefficient with repetitive error handling logic. For example, here's how I'm saving new customer records.

Note the length error checking!

```
public class CustomerRepository : IRepository<Customer>

   {

       private MyDBEntities db = new MyDBEntities();

       public uniqueIdentifier AddRecord (Customer record) {
           record.PromotionStatus = CheckForPromo(record);
           record.LastOrderID = GetLastOrderID(record);

           db.Customer.Add(record);

           try {db.SaveChanges();}
           catch (DbEntityValidationException e){
               foreach (var err in e.EntityValidationErrors){
                   Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following errors", err.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, err.Entry.State);

                   foreach (var innerErr in err.ValidationErrors){
                       Console.WriteLine("--Property of \"{0}\"  has error \"{1}\"" , innerErr.PropertyName, innerErr.ErrorMessage);
                   }
               }
           }
           return record.id;
       }//end of AddRecord 

   }
```

I have a couple different classes modeled in EF and in my tables, like so:

- Customer
- Promotions
- Messages

Each of them has a very similar looking save block like this:

```
       db.Customer.Add(record);

       try {db.SaveChanges();}
       catch (DbEntityValidationException e){
           foreach (var err in e.EntityValidationErrors){
               Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following errors", err.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, err.Entry.State);

               foreach (var innerErr in err.ValidationErrors){
                   Console.WriteLine("--Property of \"{0}\"  has error \"{1}\"" , innerErr.PropertyName, innerErr.ErrorMessage);
               }
           }
       }
```

The only thing different between them is whether it is `db.Customer.Add(record);`, or `db.Promotion.Add(record);` or so on.

I thought I could add a new method to my repo like this

```
private void TrySaveRecord(string recordType, object record){
       db.recordType.Add(record);

       try {db.SaveChanges();}
           catch (DbEntityValidationException e){
               foreach (var err in e.EntityValidationErrors){
                   Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following errors", err.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, err.Entry.State);

                   foreach (var innerErr in err.ValidationErrors){
                       Console.WriteLine("--Property of \"{0}\"  has error \"{1}\"" , innerErr.PropertyName, innerErr.ErrorMessage);
                   }
               }
           }

   }
```

But I ran into an issue of `MyDbEntities does not contain a definition for 'recordType'`.  Since then I've been spiraling around a whirlpool of depression, feels like this is probably doable but I don't know the vocabulary for this domain to figure out how to describe what I'm trying to do.

Thanks for any pointers :)

Comment: If the user (me ) passes in `TrySaveRecord(customer, record)`, I was hoping that my code would swap `Customer` in for `recordType` and then run the .Add method on that entity type.  

Maybe there is a way to retrieve a specific entity type and call save on it?

Comment: Why would you wrap a repository pattern around a repository pattern?  That seems to be inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can handle it.

The most obvious is to let `Add` outside from the helper method and handle only the `SaveChanges`.

Another way is to make your helper method generic and use `Set<T>()` method to access the associated `DbSet`:

```
private void TrySaveRecord<T>(T record)
    where T : class
{

    db.Set<T>().Add(record);
    // ...
```

Another way is to use `GetType()` and the non generic `Set(Type)` method:

```
private void TrySaveRecord(object record)
{

    db.Set(record.GetType()).Add(record);
    // ...
```

or similar, but using `Entry(object)` method and setting the `State` to `EntityState.Added` (which in EF6 is the same as calling `DbSet.Add` method):

```
private void TrySaveRecord(object record)
{

    db.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Added;
    // ...
```

Comment: Wow this is great, specifically #2 which I tested and works great.  What do you call the, uh, declaration `where T : class` in the first example?  I've never seen this before in C# (laugh if you like ) and it seems really powerful.

Comment: It's called [generic type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) - pretty standard and important part of generics.